# How to get from a restulting Matrix to its coefficients

Tags: matrix-equations

I have a given matrix A and it is multiplied with a matrix S. The result is also given. How do I get 3x3 matrix S?

$$ A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
 $$ SA=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        6 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 10 \\
        1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 5\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

As from the look of the matrix it has to be something obvious, but I just don't know what I should do.

What are the steps to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Well you know that $S\pmatrix{1 \\ 6 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{6 \\ 1 \\ 0}$ and that $S\pmatrix{2 \\ 7 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{7 \\ 2 \\ 0}$ and that $\dots$

Comment: Take only three linearly independent columns of $A$ (you get an invertible matrix) and the corresponding columns of $SA$. You have then to solve $SX=Y$, with square $S,X,Y$ and invertible $X$: multiply on the right by $X^{-1}$. Of course, it's annoying if you can't find three independent columns in $A$, because then the solution is not unique.

Comment: Ok I have tried something like this using the falksches schema and using the S as variable but I made a mistake which lead me of track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two rows are $(0,1,-8) $ and $(1,0,-3) $. The third one you can find out.

Comment: Ah thanks - I already got the 1, well sort of... I figured out -1 which made all a mess...

Comment: Are you sure about the first 2 rows? The second row seems to be $$(0,1,-3)$$

Comment: You are right.  Thanks